# Is my closet wall load bearing

Tags: walls, wood, load-bearing, closet

I wanted to take this closet out but got nervous when seeing the backed wood.

There is a floor above and the basement is below, but no support beams where the closet is.

Also the joists run with the front of the closet.

Is it safe to take out?

[image: closet]

Comment: If you do a search on this site you will find **many many questions about load bearing walls**. And they all have the same response, **you need an engineer to tell you for sure** and if you want an educated guess you need to provide all the details you can and photos of the space above etc.  Search for those questions to see how to edit your question to be better.

Comment: What is “backed wood”?

Comment: With that many studs in the walls on each side of the opening would make me wonder what the sides are supporting. I would not be concerned about the opening, but what is supported by the side walls.

Comment: @Programmer66, those studs can be explained by intersecting walls and standard layout. They're probably not arbitrarily added.

Comment: Yes - exactly they were not arbitrarily added.  You have 5 studs on the right front and 6 studs on the left front. and the whole wall has sheating. I would like to know what is above and below the wall.

Answer (score 2):

It is not unless someone totally incompetent built the home. Lumber is never used flat like that as a load-bearing header. It would need to be full-height in that head space.

*<sub>Disclaimer: I'm looking through the internet at a fuzzy photo with relatively little context. Take Alaska Man's advice and get a local expert on scene.</sub>*